# Faster alternative to proc.time()?

Tags: r

I maintain [an R package](https://github.com/ropensci/drake) that records the runtimes of many commands, and I am noticing some overhead due to `proc.time()`. Is there a faster alternative? I only need to measure things in terms of elapsed time, and I am okay with low precision.

[This example workflow](https://github.com/wlandau/drake-examples/blob/master/overhead/static.R) shows the overhead of `proc.time()` to be around 14% of the total runtime on my machine.

[image]

To confirm what I saw, I temporarily removed most of that overhead by deleting [this line](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/blob/ea8b157c393d44f9f0f3c09cf6956d811f54d2ba/R/local_build.R#L172) and replacing [this line](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/blob/ea8b157c393d44f9f0f3c09cf6956d811f54d2ba/R/local_build.R#L187) with a fixed outdated time stamp.

[image]

Individual calls to `proc.time()` are themselves quite fast, but in my case, they add up.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  proc.time()
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>         expr   min    lq    mean median    uq    max neval
#>  proc.time() 1.481 1.494 1.63657  1.501 1.546 11.744   100
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Session info

```r
devtools::session_info()
#> ─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#>  os       macOS Mojave 10.14.6        
#>  system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
#>  ui       X11                         
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
#>  tz       America/Indiana/Indianapolis
#>  date     2019-11-22                  
#> 
#> ─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
#>  package        * version    date       lib source                        
#>  assertthat       0.2.1      2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  backports        1.1.5      2019-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
#>  callr            3.3.2      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  cli              1.9.9.9000 2019-11-19 [1] Github (r-lib/cli@24a9bd8)    
#>  crayon           1.3.4      2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  desc             1.2.0      2019-08-19 [1] Github (r-lib/desc@c860e7b)   
#>  devtools         2.2.1      2019-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  digest           0.6.22     2019-10-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
#>  ellipsis         0.3.0      2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  evaluate         0.14       2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  fansi            0.4.0      2018-10-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  fs               1.3.1      2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  glue             1.3.1      2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  highr            0.8        2019-03-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  hms              0.5.2      2019-10-30 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  htmltools        0.4.0      2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  knitr            1.26       2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
#>  magrittr         1.5        2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  memoise          1.1.0      2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  microbenchmark   1.4-7      2019-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  pillar           1.4.2.9001 2019-08-19 [1] Github (r-lib/pillar@82370d7) 
#>  pkgbuild         1.0.6      2019-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  pkgconfig        2.0.3      2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
#>  pkgload          1.0.2      2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  prettyunits      1.0.2      2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  processx         3.4.1      2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  progress         1.2.2      2019-05-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  ps               1.3.0      2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  R6               2.4.1      2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
#>  Rcpp             1.0.3      2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  remotes          2.1.0      2019-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  rlang            0.4.1      2019-10-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
#>  rmarkdown        1.17       2019-11-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  rprojroot        1.3-2      2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  sessioninfo      1.1.1      2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  stringi          1.4.3      2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  stringr          1.4.0      2019-02-10 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  testthat         2.3.0      2019-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  tibble           2.1.3      2019-06-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  usethis          1.5.1.9000 2019-08-12 [1] Github (r-lib/usethis@b241420)
#>  vctrs            0.2.0      2019-07-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  withr            2.1.2      2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  xfun             0.11       2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)                
#>  yaml             2.2.0      2018-07-25 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#>  zeallot          0.1.0      2018-01-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)                
#> 
#> [1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library
```

## Edit: `get_nanotime()`

The `microbenchmark` package has a `get_nanotime()` function, but it is slower than `proc.time()` on my machine.

```r
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  microbenchmark::get_nanotime(),
  proc.time()
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>                            expr   min     lq    mean median    uq    max neval
#>  microbenchmark::get_nanotime() 5.354 5.5925 6.17782 5.7895 5.937 43.305   100
#>                     proc.time() 1.490 1.5385 1.78394 1.7505 1.873  8.025   100
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but can't you replace `proc.time` with `microbenchmark::microbenchmark` setting `times = 1`? Or use `bench::mark()`?

Comment: `microbenchmark` has `get_nanotime()`, but it is slower than `proc.time()` on my machine (see the edit). I am running with `microbenchmark(times = 1)` right now, and it is already noticeably slower. `bench::mark()` measures a bunch of other stuff in addition to time, so I am not optimistic.

Comment: Ok, it was just an idea. I have tested `bench::hires_time()` and it's faster than `proc.time()`.

Comment: Yeah, your first idea was definitely worth testing. And thanks for the tip about bench::hires_time(). I will check it out.

Comment: Confirmed: `hires_time()` is > 10x faster on the Mac and Linux machines I have tried. If you post it as a solution, I will accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are alternatives to base R's `proc.time()` function. Two packages that have similar functions are

- `microbenchmark`, function `get_nanotime()`.
- `bench`, function `hires_time()`

In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001524/faster-alternative-to-proc-time#comment104257333_59001524) to the question the OP says that it is

> Confirmed: `hires_time()` is > 10x faster on the Mac and Linux machines I have tried.

The tests below were run with R 3.6.1 on Ubuntu 19.04 and the results are not so drastic but `bench::hires_time` is the fastest of the three.

```
library(bench)
library(microbenchmark)

mb <- microbenchmark(
  microb = get_nanotime(),
  bench = hires_time(),
  Rbase = proc.time()
)
print(mb, order = 'median')
#Unit: microseconds
#   expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval cld
#  bench 1.107 1.1690 2.03060 1.2320 1.2755 80.835   100   a
# microb 2.006 2.0435 2.46541 2.1200 2.1750 35.431   100   a
#  Rbase 2.517 2.6520 2.87621 2.7085 2.7840 16.246   100   a

ggplot2::autoplot(mb)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I plan to implement your advice: https://github.com/ropensci/drake/issues/1078.